# Set title for contextual action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to set the title for the contextual action bar (like in the image below).
[image]

I have tried the following:

```
getActionBar().setTitle("Title for cab");
```

but title is not showing up.

Comment: I manage to set the title by calling setTitle method of ActionMode. mActionMode.setTitle("Title for cab");

Comment: you should write this up as the answer

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I manage to set the title by calling setTitle method of ActionMode.

```
mActionMode.setTitle("Title for cab");
```

Answer (score 5):

This answer worked for me

```
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {

        mode.setTitle(yourTitlehere);
        return false; // Return false if nothing is done
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to Android documentation:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CAB

It can be done at the overriden `onItemCheckedStateChanged()` method, when creating the `MultiChoiceModeListener` object.

This would do the trick.  Neat and simple:

```
@Override
public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position,
                                      long id, boolean checked) {
    // Set contextual action bar title
    mode.setTitle("Your title");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you aren't talking about a static setting of the text, and that you want to change it at runtime. If so, @AmJay's method should work. If not, then you should be using android:title in your menu's item creation.